# Multiple languages in cakephp using 2-letter instead of 3-letter in URL

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, multilingual

I am putting together a multilingual site according to the tutorial: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/

However, the tutorial uses three letter notation for different languages (`eng`, `rus`) and I would like to use two letters only.

I changed `config/core.php`

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'en');
```

then also `config/routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}'));
```

and also the path to:

```
locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
```

but it is still not working. Strings turn out as their default and not read from the `.po` files.

The `.po` files, i got from runing cake i18n to generate one single `.pot` file that i then renamed to `.po` and copied in each directory for each language.

the `.po` files are utf-8 encoded.

i also have in my `config/bootstrap.php`:

```
Configure::write('Config.languages', array(
    'en' => array(
    'language' => 'English',
    'locale' => 'en',
    'localeFallback' => 'en',
    'charset' => 'utf-8'
    ),
    'bg' => array(
    'language' => 'Bulgarian',
    'locale' => 'bg',
    'localeFallback' => 'bg',
    'charset' => 'utf-8'
    ),
)
);
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the i18n internals just to change how the URLs look like. Leave everything else alone except the route configuration and at the start of `_setLanguage()` function convert the 2-letter language codes to 3-letter codes. (`_setLanguage()` being the function mentioned in the tutorial you linked to.)

For example, if you know that you'll be supporting only 2-3 languages it's easiest to do the conversion manually:

```
function _setLanguage() {
    if ($this->Cookie->read('lang') && !$this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->Cookie->read('lang'));
    }
    else if (isset($this->params['language']) && ($this->params['language']
             !=  $this->Session->read('Config.language'))) {

// ADD THIS
        switch( $this->params['language'] ) {
            case 'bg':
                $lang = 'bul';
                break;
            case 'en':
            default:
                $lang = 'eng';
                break;
        }

        $this->Session->write('Config.language', $lang);
        $this->Cookie->write('lang', $lang, false, '20 days');
    }
}
```

Now everything will work using 3-letter language codes under the hood but you can provide 2-letter codes to the user.

Comment: I am sorry, how would i do this? i am quite a newbie and i am not sure i understand you

Comment: Also, now that I have changed everything already, isn't it better to use everything 2-letter? It sounds like the better option, no?

Comment: Sure, if it works, but you asked the question because it doesn't work, right? :)  See the edited answer.

Comment: Well, I guess If I had made a small mistake, but could be fixed I would prefer everything to be 2-letter. But if no one comes that knows where the problem could be, I would go with your solution. thanks!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1229/Internationalizing-Your-Application): "The three-character locale codes conform to the [ISO 639-2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) standard, although if you create regional locales (en_US, en_GB, etc.) cake will use them if appropriate." So it seems, under the hood, CakePHP doesn't recognize two-letter, only 3-letter or 2-letter with _locale. (eg. `'locale' => 'en_us'`)

Answer (score 0):

I find very interesting also the possibility to AUTO discover user's browser lang.

You may add an additional option this way:

...

```
}elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){
    if (ereg("bg", $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]))
        $lang = 'bul';
    if (ereg("en", $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]))
        $lang = 'eng';
}
```